# es6 syntax for exporting modules in one file

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to have an index.js that defines all my react components like this:

```
import App from './app';
import Home from './home';

export App;
export Home;
```

I then reference them in another file:

```
import { App, Home } from './components/index';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('theContent')
);
```

But I get this error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/paulcowan/projects/liverpool-managers/client/app/components/index.js: Unexpected token (4:10)
  2 | import Home from './home';
  3 | 
> 4 | export App;
    |           ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

export as shown below.

```
import App from './app';
import Home from './home';

export {App, Home};
```

Hope this one works for you.

Alternatively, you can write your import as below (named object reference)

```
import * as Components from './components/index';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={Components.App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Components.Home}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('theContent')
);
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not the correct way to use `export`

this

```
export App;
export Home;
```

should be

```
export {App, Home}
```

or

```
export App from './app';
export Home from './home';
```

Comment: Note `export App from './app';` is a syntax proposal, but not official. You could do `export {default as App} from './app';` though.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue recently, and essentially `export` is not designed to be used this way - it "is used to export functions, objects or primitives" [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), not "imported modules", but you can simulate it by assigning the `import`ed modules to a plain object and then `export default`ing that object.

```
import App from './app';
import Home from './home';

const exports = {
    App,
    Home,
};

export default exports;
```

You then have to `import` the whole object, unfortunately, but if the main purpose is just to have a single module import point, that's probably not too bad.

I wouldn't be surprised if this behavior changes when we get native implementations rather than being limited by transpilers, but this solution isn't too verbose or unreadable.